# Calling executable FLAC (Itasca software) from command line and from batch file (*.bat) different behavior

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'd like to run [FLAC](https://www.itascainternational.com/products/software/geotechnical-software#flac) using a batch file in particular I need to run FLAC data files using the command "call".
However, if I call FLAC from the prompt manually by actually typing FLAC I can do it. 
If I run FLAC from a *.bat file I cannot.
Please see the two pictures attached which refer to the call of the command HELP from *.bat file and manual typing.

Manual typing of FLAC HELP:
[image: Manual typing of FLAC HELP]

FLAC HELP called from *.bat file:
[image: FLAC HELP called from *.bat file]

As you can see the command CALL can be called only manually (apparently)

For the sake of clarity my batch script is shown below

```
C:
cd C:\Program Files\Itasca\FLAC800\exe64
flac800_64.exe help
```

Any idea why and how to work this out?

Comment: You can always try [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) (3.x recommended). It can issue commands from the command line via [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) (i.e. `from subprocess import call` then use `call(...)` to call flac call =P). Not a guarantee, but if flac is limiting the commands available in a batch file, this could potentially bypass the issue.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't seem easy to download and test for others where you have to register an email address, etc. Try using `START "" flac800_64.exe call` and see what happens from the batch command. If I could get access to it, scan it to ensure it's safe, and then test in a sandbox VM I would but cannot find direct download.

Comment: @ITSnuggles I can share the installation file. It works as a working demo and you can test it, if you like.

Comment: @ITSnuggles by the way it does not work, nothing changes with or without the use of START.

Comment: Okay, I assume it doesn't come with a support email address you could shoot a quick note to with the example as you provided either, right? If you send me a link to a download I'll take a look when I can but if you've been thorough then it may be an app bug, limitation, etc. but I'll be happy to try. The Python may not be a bad idea by the way.

Comment: @ITSnuggles FLAC uses FISH language and the only workaround seems to write a FISH file and run it within FLAC command line. I'll try Python anyway. Is there any possibility of sharing a link privately. I think I cannot share a public link here.